Custom placeholder element not recognized as placeholder for accessibility
I have a form with normal input fields and placeholder and they don't get flagged by the lighthouse test for accessibility.
There is also a multiselect component in this form which uses a custom span that is placed over the multiselect field to be used as the 'placeholder'
I use Vue3 so there is a lot of generated HTML and for the multiselect it looks like this:
<div class="multiselect__tags">
  <div class="multiselect__tags-wrap" style="display: none;"></div>  
  <div class="multiselect__spinner" style="display: none;"></div>
  <input name="" id="id_06360327365008687" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Selecteer categorie" tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" aria-controls="listbox-id_06360327365008687" style="width: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px;">
  <span class="multiselect__placeholder">Selecteer categorie</span>
</div>

Which looks like this in the frontend

Now the span multiselect__placeholder will get flagged by lighthouse as having not enough color contrast.

Is there a way for instance with aria attributes or something totally different to link this placeholder element to the actual input field so that it is compliant for Lighthouse and any accessibility checker?
Thanks in advance

It never stated that there was no placeholder here. Rather the contrast is low but for such an element it is totally fine. You could work around with it thanks to some CSS but it's nothing else than color contrast so far. You could use the browser devtools to find some better color value but it's more of the domain of UX and how you want to handle the whole flow of your forms. The placeholder is properly generated, Vue did its job and the accessibility is fine from an HTML POV. The rest is styling and how you want to handle it. Could also totally ignore that one cuz it's okay for a placeholder

@kissu Was thinking indeed for a CSS solution but the 'problem' is that the placeholders of all the fields are the same at the moment. A bit why i'm somewhat confused that this give the contrast issue. But then i think lighthouse ignores real placeholder where this is a separate DOM element :(

The easiest way to double-check that one is to add a very vivid popping green color on the placeholder text color and run lighthouse again. Otherwise, work on the background, color, border width etc. Plenty of ways to make the UX better!

Lighthouse is probably ignoring the low contrast of default placeholders because they are browser styles. A user who would want to increase default placeholder contrast could use a user stylesheet.
Still, the low contrast warning you're getting is correct, per WCAG 2.1 success criterion 1.4.3 :

The minimum contrast success criterion (1.4.3) applies to text in the page, including placeholder text [...]
— WCAG 2.1 SC 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)

This means that your UI would fail this criterion in a WCAG 2.1 AA audit, with or without Vue3. It looks like it's even more of an issue with Vue3, since a user stylesheet bumping up placeholder contrast (::placeholder) would have no effect. (And you could argue that fixing contrast in default browser styles is not your application's concern.)
The obvious problem here is that if you increase placeholder contrast, it might be mistaken for input value. The question becomes : do you really need placeholder text?
Placeholder text:

should definitely not label the input (use a <label>)
should not add extra details to the label (use aria-describedby)

...and it has a whole lot of other accessibility and usability issues. Therefore, accessibility experts argue that it would be best not to use them at all.

Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful, NN Group
The Anatomy of Accessible Forms: The Problem with Placeholders, Deque
Don’t Use The Placeholder Attribute, Eric Bailey (for Smashing mag)


I very agree, just read a paragraph about that exact idea in my accessibility book haha.
